# Set "Sales Representative" as custom attribute in Customer - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes

I created a module that save the name of the Admin logged in, into "Sales Representative" column at "sales_order" table.

It's working pretty fine.

Now i need to save the same value into custom attribute of customer.  (when a new customer is created by Admin in the customer page or create order page)

My code until now is:
**InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Store Admin Name Order table save
 *
 * @category     Store
 * @package      Store_Sales
 */
namespace Emporio\Seller\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * Install DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        //$quote = 'quote';
        $orderTable = 'sales_order';

        //Order Grid table
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($orderTable),
                'sales_representative',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Vendedor'
                ]
            );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Store Admin Name Order table save
 *
 * @category     Store
 * @package      Store_Sales
 */
 -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="store_admin_checkout_submit_all_after" instance="Emporio\Seller\Observer\AdminCheckoutSubmitAllAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**AdminCheckoutSubmitAllAfter.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Store Admin Name Order table save
 *
 * @category     Store
 * @package      Store_Sales
 */
namespace Emporio\Seller\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AdminCheckoutSubmitAllAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session
     */
    protected $backendAuthSession;
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $backendAuthSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $backendAuthSession
    ) {
        $this->backendAuthSession = $backendAuthSession;
    }

    /**
     * Add sale repsentative name to the order table
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $adminUserName = $this->backendAuthSession->getUser()->getUserName();
        if ($adminUserName) {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $order->setSalesRepresentative($adminUserName);
            $order->save();
        }
    }
}
```

What do I have to do to save the value as custom attribute of customer and save in DB ?

Answer (score 1):

To save the same attribute in customer, who will have to create 'sales_representative' attribute for customer.

1. InstallData.php/UpgradeData.php - create the eav attribute 'sales_representative'.

   ```
   /* UpgradeData.php */ 


   <?php
    namespace Emporio\Seller\Setup;

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

    class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
    {

        protected $customerSetupFactory;

        protected $customerSetup;

        public function __construct(
           CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
        ) {
           $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        }


        public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
       {
           $setup->startSetup();

           $this->customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

           $code = 'sales_representative';
           if (!$this->customerSetup->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $code)) {
             $this->customerSetup->addAttribute(
               Customer::ENTITY,
               $code,
               [
                 'type' => 'varchar',
                 'label' => 'Sales Representative',
                 'input' => 'text',
                 'required' => false,
                 'visible' => true,
                 'user_defined' => true,
                 'position' => 1000,
                 'system' => 0,
               ]
            );
         }
         $setup->endSetup();
      }
   }
   ```
2. You can use an observer "customer_register_success" to save your attribute in customer. As you only want to save admin details so we can create events.xml inside adminhtml folder.

   ```
   /* etc/adminhtml/events.xml */

   <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="save_admin_customer_register_success" 
           instance="Emporio\Seller\Observer\Customer\SaveRepresentative"/>
   </event>
   ```
3. Our Observer file will save that attribute

   ```
   /* Emporio\Seller\Observer\Customer\SaveRepresentative.php */

   class SaveRepresentative implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
   {

       /**
        * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session
        */
        protected $backendAuthSession;

        public function __construct(
           \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $backendAuthSession
        ) {
           $this->backendAuthSession = $backendAuthSession;
        }

       public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
       {
          $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
          $adminUserName = $this->backendAuthSession->getUser()->getUserName();
          if ($adminUserName) {
              $customer->setData('sales_representative', $adminUserName);
              $customer->save();
          }

          return $this;
       }
   }
   ```
4. to show the attribute value in order grid

> Create sales_order_grid.xml file under app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
  <columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <column name="short_name" class="Vendor/Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Representative">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Representative</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
  </columns>
</listing>
```

5. to show the value in order view information section, override the info template

> Create sales_order_view.xml file under app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Will continue saving on DB (sales_order) and as custom attribute with this code ?   Or only will save like custom attribute ?

Comment: Yes, this will be saved like a custom attribute.

Comment: I got this error while installing the module:   Notice: Undefined property: Emporio\Seller2\Setup\InstallData                                                                                                             ::$customerSetup in /var/www/clients/client1/web10/web/app/code/Emporio/Seller2/                                                                                                             Setup/InstallData.php on line 58

Comment: Could you give me the full "InstallData.php" file ?

Comment: sure adding full content. But as you have your module already installed, you should write your code in UpgradeData.php

Comment: Now i could install the module.  But unfortunately after place the order didn't save the custom attribute.    =(

Comment: you want to save the customer 'sales_representative' attribute on order placement also?

Comment: There is two ways to solve my need.   The first one is save the Admin User as Customer Custom Attribute when a new customer is created by "create order page".    Or simply create a custom block on Order View to show the value already saved on "sales_representative" column of "sales_order" table.  Could you help me ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109396/discussion-between-afreen-sheikh-and-gustavo-lopes).